# get the error code in wp-login

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, error-code

I am using wordpress to login into the site.and i want to get the error at place of the string .means i want error code like 1,2,3 etc . 
is it possible ??
my code is

```
if(isset($_POST['appcara_uname']) && isset($_POST['appcara_pwd']))
{
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['appcara_uname'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['appcara_pwd'];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
    {
        $error=$user->get_error_message();
        print_r(WP_error());
    }else
    {
        wp_redirect(home_url());

    }
}
```

Comment: set `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `true` in wp-config.php file and dont forget to `exit;` after `wp_redirect()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use **get_error_code();** to display error code.